# GB2ShapeCache Remove plist - Physics Editor

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, game-physics

Could someone please advise how to remove plist from GB2ShapeCache sharedcache. I have been googling around but no luck. I could find any remove methods in the GB2ShapeCache class.

This class is the way to load plist of physics shapes into cocos2d/box2d project.

Comment: you have to add the remove method yourself. Typically not needed though, the amount of memory used by shapes is tiny compared to textures.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I agree the memory usage is low. I have different themes in my game, thus different asset sprite atlas & shapes plist. I do want to reuse the tag names. So removing previously cached plist will not clash tag names. If you have any ideas how to achieve my goal, or a better way of implementing, I'm all ears.

Comment: I suppose it'S as simple as removing all objects from shape cache's internal dictionary

Comment: Thank you sir. I'll give that a try when I get home from work this evening.